# hosting multiple github pages from one github repository

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages, web-hosting

I have github repository which contains 4 different folders named module2/3/4/5 solutions respectively each containing index.html and style.css files which are a part of a coursera course i am currently pursuing....now i can't figure out how to host all these 4 different pages separately from this one repository....all tutorials and documentation tell to create a new repo named username.github.io and simply push the index.html and it'll work which i understand....but i don't want 4 different repositories for solutions of different weeks...rather i would like to host all 4 independently form this very same repository....please tell me what to do?

I want my repository to look like this guys repsitory

https://github.com/siddartha19/Coursera-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript-for-Web-Developers

as you can see all the different module solutions are hosted from this repository....

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of the github page website mirror the architecture of the repository.

From your example, one of the page's URL is:

```
https://siddartha19.github.io/Coursera-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript-for-Web-Developers/Assignments/module-3/index.html
```

The repository name is 'Coursera-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript-for-Web-Developers' - It contains a folder 'Assignments' which contains 'module-3' which contains an index.html file.

Do you see how the URL format mirrors the structure of the folders?

If you want your github page to have the same architecture you can just do the same folder structure.

Comment: my repo is built in the same structure but my problem is I don't know how to host such a repo.The tutorials say to create github repo named username.github.io and it'll work but obviously for a repo like this with folders inside them and to host different index.html in different folders this change of name of repo isn't enough.If u can give me the steps for the simple case where repo name is what i want like"coursera assignment " and it contains folders.How to host index.html in say module 2 folder then i will be able to follow the steps for all such folders...

Comment: There are two ways to host pages on github, at least according to this article https://shoehornwithteeth.com/ramblings/2016/12/redirecting-github-pages-after-renaming-a-repository/

One of the ways is renaming the repository, the other is using a branch as a publish source : https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site

The second solution might be what you're looking for.

Comment: is it possible to host multiple github pages from different branches ?